# Contar dados de uma tabela para soma

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Olá pessoal estou crando um *Dashboard* e me deparei com um desafio e nao sei o que fazer.

**Tabela Ordem de Serviços**

```
Nome_do_profissional = Susana  
Serviço = MegaHair   
Valor = 80
```

Eu preciso criar uma consulta que conte quantas vezes o nome se repete na coluna
`Nome-do-profissional`, e multiplicar pelo valor que ela receberia como pagamento, exemplo:

```
$quatidade = 5;
$valorTipoDeServiço = 80;
$pagamento =  5 * 80;
```

detalhe, esse valor a ser multiplicado não é o mesmo registrado na tabela
ele estará em outra tabela:

**Tabela TIPO Serviços**

```
Serviços = Mega Hair  
Valor = 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Natan. Para isso, você vai precisar usar relacionamento entre tabelas e o agrupamento de dados do SQL.

Suponhamos que temos a tabela `ordens` com a seguinte estrutura:

```
`ordens`
nome_do_profissional  |   servico
Susana                |   MegaHair
Joana                 |   MegaHair
```

E a tabela `servicos` com:

```
`servicos`
nome             |   valor
MegaHair         |   80
```

Veja que `servico` e `nome_do_servico` serão nossas chaves para relacionarmos os dados entre uma tabela e a outra. Com isso, utilizando as funções [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) e um [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), podemos fazer:

```sql
SELECT
    nome_do_profissional,
    SUM(servicos.valor) as valor_total
FROM
    ordens
LEFT JOIN
    servicos
ON
    ordens.servico = servicos.nome
GROUP BY
    ordens.nome_do_profissional
```

Isso nos retornará dados onde teremos nome_do_profissional em uma coluna e o valor_total acumulará o valor total de todos os serviços realizados por esse profissional.

Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3fc4b/22/0

Comment: Fantástico amigo. mas como eu imprimo isso no meu html em tabela.
pois no meu html eu teria:  

 <table>  
  
  <!-- linha superior -->
  <td>
  <td>Nome</td>
  <td>Mega Hair</td>
  <td>Corte</td>
  <td>Valor a Receber</td>
  </tr>
  <?php while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   # code...
   ?>
  <!-- Linha inferio -->
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $dados['Nome_do_profissional']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $dados['MegaHair']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $dados['corte']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
 </table>

Comment: Agora eu não estou entendendo o problema direito. Você precisa pegar o valor total a ser recebido pelo funcionário ou é outra coisa? Essa query que eu lhe mostrei vai buscar o valor total a ser recebido pelo funcionário.

Comment: Você está correto!
preciso pegar o quanto o funcionário irá receber, e imprimir em meu html,
se possivel em uma TABLE
desculpa sou iniciante em PHP

Comment: Faça como está nesse gist e deve funcionar: https://gist.github.com/jpedroh/ebc66b9dae065b3fdf679619a0015450

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou alguma query ja?

Testa esse exemplo :

```
SELECT COUNT(Nome_do_profissional), valor
FROM Servicos
WHERE Nome_do_profissional = 'Susana';
```

Comment: sim usei exatamente essa logica, acho que meu problema esta em salvar o resultado da query em uma string, e multiplica-la pelo valor do registro de uma segunda tabela.

Comment: como você está salvando na variavel o resultado hoje, edita seu post e coloca essas informações para que possa conseguir te ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

TENTA ADAPTAR

```
DECLARE @nome  nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @valor nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT 
    @nome = (SELECT COUNT('NOME') AS nome,
    @valor = (SELECT SUM('VALOR') AS valor
FROM consultas;    

SET @query = '
    SELECT *
    FROM {nome} as a  
    WHERE a.{valor} = @valor
';
```

> Um exemplo usando SQL, a lógica é salvar os resultados dos dois
>   selects em duas variaveis e depois montar uma query com esses
>   resultado.